# How to get URL as a string of an image using the image picker to POST to an API for processing?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make the user choose a picture from their photo album to upload to an API and get some data back. The problem is that I don't know if this is correct to upload an image from the iPhone.

I've been trying to upload the image's URL to the API. I keep trying to get the string from the URL, but when I try to retrieve it, it gives me an error that the UTF can't be determined. I then use utf16 but it gives me a string with a bunch of weird text characters that is hundreds of characters long.

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {

    let pickedImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as! URL
    let pickedImageStr = try! String(contentsOf: pickedImageURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf16)
    ImageAPI.call(with: pickedImageStr)

    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

The weird thing is that Xcode terminal tells me the exact path as a string when I don't use the UTF parameter at all. It gives me the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The file “E4DF0E72-1E7E-45FA-A5A2-A03850EC182D.jpeg” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/351FF152-79C7-447E-9964-2C150368946D/tmp/E4DF0E72-1E7E-45FA-A5A2-A03850EC182D.jpeg}
```

So how come when I try to get the URL as a string, it doesn't work and gives me a string hundreds of characters long with a bunch of weird symbols??

If I were to just copy and paste the file location given in the terminal, I get an error that says the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {

let pickedImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as! URL
let pickedImageStr = pickedImageURL.description
ImageAPI.call(with: pickedImageStr)

dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

String(contentsOf: URL) method is show file in URL address by string, not create String by url